# how to display another data from the same database table dynamically when some value is selected from drop down list?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in programming and I'm having difficulties..

i want to display a data from the same database table when the first value is selected from the drop down list..can anyone help me with that?

what i mean is, 
i have a product name and quantity in the database table,and the product name is dynamically display in a drop down list. when one of the product name is selected, the quantity of that product will be display in a text field and it is editable..

can anyone help me how to do it or maybe some references on how to do it.

thanks in advanced..

Comment: use the ajax to interact with database.

Comment: Javascript, jQuery and AJAX will be your friend here. Depending on how you want to do it you can perhaps ignore the AJAX part and just pull all the data at once and use pure Javascript/jQuery. Depends on your data sizes and loading time requirements.

Comment: Basically you want to update the information that is in the database table from the UI? If so then you want to create an update stored procedure and call that within your form, this will then mean that if the ui textbox quantity is changed it will send the new information back to the database so in theory it saves the information.

Answer (score 1):

This is too large a topic to be addressed here. I think you need to sit down with a good book or decent online tutorial and work through the basics of PHP and MySQL, and then by all means come back with any specific difficulties you may have.